# How do I call results from all pages from an API when the max displayed by the API is 50?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I want to make a change in my script.js file to be able to concatenate results upto atleast 10 pages called from the api.
Please refer to line 10 below - results=results.concat('&page=1');

```
const loc = document.getElementById("locationcity").value;
const start = document.getElementById("startdate").value;
const end = document.getElementById("enddate").value;
var results = baseUrl + '/location?name=';
results=results.concat(loc);
results=results.concat('&minDate=');
results=results.concat(start);
results=results.concat('&maxDate=');
results=results.concat(end);
results=results.concat('&page=1');
const url=results;
const res = await fetch(url);  
const record = await res.json();
```

When i change the code to results=results.concat('&page=10') or results=results.concat('&page=6'); it will show me what is on that page but i want to know how to call a range eg. from page 1 to 10. Have tried & and + but it isn't working.

Comment: "Have tried & and + but it isn't working." --- Is there any documentation for this API? Because reading the docs is better than trying things; I should know, because I read some documentation yesterday, when I wanted to export data from one program and import it into another.

Comment: I've removed your sensitive data from the code example. You also may want to revoke your api key and create a new one since everyone can see the current one in the edit history.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking into the API documentation we can just guess.

It might be that the API does offer a feature like `&page=1&page=2&page=3...` to concatenate all pages to a single response but it is unlikely since the reason for pagination is to page over the results. So I guess you can only send a single page and as you noticed already the API seems to chose the last `page` parameter that you send, ignoring the others.

If my guess is correct, you need to do `10` requests to get `10` pages.

```
const loc = document.getElementById("locationcity").value;
const start = document.getElementById("startdate").value;
const end = document.getElementById("enddate").value;

var records = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var results = baseUrl + '/location?name=';
    const url = results
            .concat(loc)
            .concat('&minDate=')
            .concat(start)
            .concat('&maxDate=')
            .concat(end)
            .concat('&page=')
            .concat(i);
    const res = await fetch(url);  
    const record = await res.json();
    records.push(record);
}
```

Then you can do something with all the results in that array to combine them in a single result, like concat existing array, flatten or something, depending on how your data (the jsons) look like.

Comment: hey! thanks soo much for this, it did help to some extent but now it just displays each page for a second and loops to the next page and the next, to finally end at a blank screen. Could you help me out with how to fix this? Like you've mentioned above to combine them all into a single static result - not sure of how to do that. New to coding!

Comment: For that I would have to know how the result of `res.json()` looks like. You'll see that if you print it to console or set a breakpoint in debugger. Lets assume it is an array. Then our `records` variable will hold an array of those arrays like `[[{...},{...}],[{...},{...}]` for two page results with two entries each. If this is true, all you need to do is to do `var flattened = records.flatMap(x => x)` and use that for your UI work.

Comment: So the results are in the format of Artist, Date and Location that is being taken from the API source data using document.getElementById("concerts").innerHTML = record.data.map ........... How do i go about naming the (x => x) in flatMap correctly?

Comment: That still does not explain how the result looks like. Is res.json an array or a json object? For the x=>x, there is no need for rename. Flatmap takes an array of arrays and flattens it to a single array. Yea it looks strange but it just means "map it to the same value while flatmapping" so that each value from the nested arrays become the same value in the new array.

Comment: it would be a json object, seems like

Comment: Then it could be that you need a lot more manual processing depending how the json looks like. Can't tell without knowing the API. Can you copy an example response from the api somewhere to a paste-site?